# Spring ClassPathXmlApplicationContext NullPointerException

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

Trying to use spring. The xml file is under src. I've searched and cannot find the problem. Seems it cant find the xml file.

I get the following error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.suppressGetenvAccess(AbstractEnvironment.java:406)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getSystemEnvironment(AbstractEnvironment.java:368)
at org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment.customizePropertySources(StandardEnvironment.java:79)
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.<init>(AbstractEnvironment.java:124)
at org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment.<init>(StandardEnvironment.java:54)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.createEnvironment(AbstractApplicationContext.java:444)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getEnvironment(AbstractApplicationContext.java:283)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.resolvePath(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:122)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.setConfigLocations(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:80)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:137)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at org.hancock.javabrains.DrawingApp.main(DrawingApp.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.core.SpringProperties.<clinit>(SpringProperties.java:58)
... 12 more
```

This is the line causing an error (By changing Beans.xml to an erroneous name I still get same error):

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
```

The xml (Beans.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">

<bean id="helloWorld" class="org.hancock.javabrains.HelloWorld">
   <property name="message" value="Hello World!"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: show the entire stacktrace

Comment: what is the name of .xml file? is it `Beans.xml` or `beans.xml`?

Comment: Alright added. It is called Beans.xml

Comment: The classloader is null. In which environment are you running this application?

Comment: Execution Environment: JavaSE-1.7

Answer (score 0):

Try this by giving the full file path

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
```

Comment: Seems like your are using pre spring 4.0 libraries but referring to spring-beans-4.0.xsd in your schema location in xml. Try to use the latest spring libraries and see. Spring 4 does not have a file SpringProperties.java.

Comment: All the JARS say 4.0.3. And if I change it to spring-beans-3.0.xsd I get the same error.